# failed Error al crear Proyecto en Angular Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, npm, angular-cli

El comando usado es para crear un proyecto

C:\Users\javcanc0>ng new appCurso
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SCSS   [ https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss                ]
CREATE appCurso/angular.json (3670 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/package.json (1251 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/README.md (1025 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/tsconfig.json (489 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/tslint.json (3125 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/karma.conf.js (1020 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/tsconfig.app.json (210 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/index.html (294 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/polyfills.ts (2835 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/styles.scss (80 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/test.ts (753 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (246 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/app/app.component.html (25757 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1065 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/app/app.component.ts (213 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/src/app/app.component.scss (0 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (641 bytes)
CREATE appCurso/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)
/ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint.
Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgradeto chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\rollup\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json.192361851
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json.192361851' -> 'C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json.192361851' -> 'C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json.192361851' -> 'C:\Users\javcanc0\appCurso\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\p-locate\package.json'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\javcanc0\\appCurso\\node_modules\\@angular\\compiler-cli\\node_modules\\p-locate\\package.json.192361851',
npm ERR!     dest: 'C:\\Users\\javcanc0\\appCurso\\node_modules\\@angular\\compiler-cli\\node_modules\\p-locate\\package.json'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\javcanc0\\appCurso\\node_modules\\@angular\\compiler-cli\\node_modules\\p-locate\\package.json.192361851',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\javcanc0\\appCurso\\node_modules\\@angular\\compiler-cli\\node_modules\\p-locate\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: '@angular/compiler-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\javcanc0\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-14T01_31_32_668Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: Cierra cualquier programa que este intentando abrir el archivo, desactiva los antivirus y elimina cualquier archivo, archivos o carpetas que angular haya intentado crear a la hora de hacer el proyecto, incluyendo modulos de `nodejs`, luego vuelve a intentarlo pero ejecutando la terminal como administrador.

Answer (score 0):

1.npm cache clear - - force(prueba sin el - - force primero).
2.ng new nombreProyecto